# How to parse date in UTC format using java

Tags: java

How to parse the following date in UTC format `2013-01-12T12:00:00Z` using java

Comment: SimpleDateFormat, but I failed

Comment: @Sam show us your code .

Comment: What's `T1e` in `2013-01-12T1e2:00:00Z`?

Comment: May be this will help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
System.out.println(
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
   .parse("2013-01-12T102:00:00-0400"));
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");

            Date date = formatter.parse("2013-01-12T12:00:00Z");

Comment: doesnt work for 2013-01-12T12:00:00Z

Comment: @Sam `Z` - it's time zone, it can't be just letter `Z`. replace it to `-0400`

Comment: how do I go from a java.util.Date to the above format

Answer (score 0):

In think [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is what you need.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(yourString)
```

Comment: Updated with a sample :)